# Why is my donut rendering gray and unclear?

Tags: modeling, rendering

The light settings are all identical to those in the tutorial and im pretty sure the lamp is pointing at the donut and I've also tried flipping the donut upside down and stuff. I'm clearly a beginner

[image: Donut looks all grey in the render window but normal in the regular window]

Donut looks all grey in the render window but normal in the regular window

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your light settings are probably pretty dim. try increasing the wattage in the object data properties of the light. or use an HDRI which is even better. you can also share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: To understand what is wrong with the light in your scene it would be best to not only show the donut, but also the light(s) and their settings. Also a screenshot of the complete _3D Viewport_ and the _Outliner_ might help to find out if there are some options/settings that might lead to this appearance.

Comment: This looks typical of setting the Viewport mode to 'Rendered' and its options to 'Scene Lights' and 'Scene World' , with the scene having the default grey world and  default point light.